# difference between onetomany and manytomany annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

i've a Many to Many relationship on my DB, and i do that with a Join Table, 
in Hibernate i've to use @ManyToMany between the two entity or @OneToMany from Entity1 to JoinTable and then @ManyToOne from Entity2 to JoinTable?

It's not a question about the db theory but i want understand the hibernate annotation.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would specify that by using a `@ManyToMany` in addition with a `@JoinTable` that describes the special join-table you already have and the column mappings between the two entity types.

Additional, you would use a `@OneToMany` / `@ManyToOne` when the relationship between entities when you can only have One entity type associated to many others.  In those cases, you don't necessarily need a join table to manage the relationship, but you can imply that using a `@JoinTable` annotation if needed.